# groupby same partial string of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've been using pandas to export JSON data to a csv file. Now, I've been asked to group this data and get the sum for each date grouped by `system`. Below is an example of my DataFrame.

**DataFrame:**

```
system,totalCapacity,totalLocatedCapacity,availableCapacity,date
aadata02,96155472,99924183,39116616,20170728
aadata02,41943174,41614541,15946266,20170728
aadata03,52764600,50966017,13839882,20170728
aadata03,52764600,44043720,15503376,20170728
aadata03,37373700,35654440,7073598,20170728
...
bbdata01,38473680,25168248,24006696,20170728
bbdata01,17585400,14681478,11711826,20170728
bbdata01,22015224,6907992,20668746,20170728
```

I have started with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

csvin = "test.csv"
csvout = "test2.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(csvin)
col = ['site', 'totalPoolCapacity', 'totalLocatedCapacity',
       'availableVolumeCapacity', 'date']
df = df.groupby('date', as_index=False).sum()
df['site'] = pd.Series('aa', index=df.index)
with open(csvout, 'w+') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, index=False, header=True, columns=col)
```

This only sums everything by date and puts everything under site `aa`. How can I modify my code to have it output in the following way:

```
site,totalCapacity,totalLocatedCapacity,availableCapacity,date
aa,903240114,735713005,421348788,20170728
bb,78074304,46757718,56387268,20170728
```

Comment: Do you want everything starting with aa, bb etc to be grouped together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
df.groupby([df.system.str[:2], 'date']).sum().reset_index()

    system  date    totalCapacity   totalLocatedCapacity    availableCapacity
0   aa      20170728    281001546   272202901               91479738
1   bb      20170728    78074304    46757718                56387268
```

Comment: thank you! It's close to what I'm looking for. The last thing I'm looking to do is change the column name from `system` to `site`. I've tried adding `df.rename(index=str, columns={'system': 'site'})`, but it will error out because it's looking for `system`. I guess the best thing to do is write to the csv first and reopen the csv to change the column name.

Comment: For renaming column, try df.groupby([df.system.str[:2], 'date']).sum().reset_index().rename(columns = {'system': 'site'}). And thank you for accepting. Happy weekend!